# Arduino Serial.write() Missing Data

Tags: python, c, string, arduino

I'm reading data from Serial2 and writing data to Serial3 on Arduino like this:

```
Serial3.write(Serial2.read());
```

I am writing a concatenated string from Python that looks like this:

```
myNum = readADC(2)
myString = "The Number: " + str(myNum)
print(myString);
```

The output of the above code an empty string.

If I do `print("some string " + myNum)` I get:

```
some string
```

If I do `print(myNum)` I get:

say, `32`

Printing myString to the Python console shows the expected output.

It looks like `Serial.write(data)` is doing something to the string.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Serial.Write() doesn't change anything if the variable is string. Problems occur when you try to change type, for instance string '0' to int results int 48. Problem must be caused by Python code.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to convert an int to a string in Python?

Comment: Maybe there is, but str() is just fine. No problem with that.

Comment: Then how would you write this data to Serial3?

Comment: I am preparing the answer. I hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `Serial.read()` returns 1 byte of data. I am surprised you get `"The Number"` string.

I recommend you to

- Read incoming bytes with an iteration

```c
char IncomingString[14];
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readBytes(IncomingString, 14);// Assuming myNum is 2 bytes data
}
```

From now on you have your string. You can use `Serial.write(IncomingString)`

- Send `"The Number: "` and myNum consequtively.

```c
print("The Number: ");
print(str(myNum));
```